# How to close the re-circulation flap?

Tags: chevrolet, ac, malibu

I have a 2001 Chevy Malibu and I am having a problem with the re-circulation switch for the AC. I am trying to figure out how to close flap so there is no outside air coming in can anybody help me with that problem. Thanks

Comment: Is it not working or do you not know how to operate it? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Is it mechanical or electronic?

Comment: Electronic. There are two buttons below the knob for the speed of the fan. One button has an arrow going into the car, that's fresh are. The second button has an arrow in a circle inside the car, that's recirculate.

Comment: Those buttons don't work and havent worked since I bought the car. So my guess is its stuck open.  Vini_i

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so, please post an answer.